# How to download Sentinel2 L1C using AWS Python SDK (boto3)

Tags: python, sentinel-2, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

The permissions for Sentinel2 L1C changed today

https://www.sentinel-hub.com/faq/how-will-access-permission-changes-aws-bucket-affect-users-accessing-data-directly-non-sentinel#

How can I send a 'requester pays' header when using boto3?

My previous code (below) which worked previously is now hitting a 403

```
  s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
  bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
  bucket.download_file(key, fpath)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a sample code that should work (given that your config and credentials are saved in `~/.aws`)

```
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.Session().client('s3')
response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket='sentinel-s2-l1c',
                                Key='tiles/7/W/FR/2018/3/31/0/B01.jp2', 
                                RequestPayer='requester')
response_content = response['Body'].read()

with open('./B01.jp2', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(response_content)
```

I extracted this code from what we have implemented in `sentinelhub` Python package. The full code is available [here](https://github.com/sentinel-hub/sentinelhub-py/blob/649cdc512a74346f98385747ecca107209eaa3e2/sentinelhub/download.py#L280) and is basically also handling multithreaded download and certain errors which can occur during download.

By the way, `sentinelhub` supports download of Sentinel-2 L1C and L2A data from AWS: [examples](http://sentinelhub-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/aws_request.html#Download-data).

Comment: Hours googling, hours I say, until I hit upon the right search terms to bring me here!

Comment: Do I need to set up a SentinelHub account in order to just download the Sentinel data from S3 using SentinelHub?

Comment: No, for downloading from S3 with `sentinelhub` package you don't need a Sentinel Hub account.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to set the `ExtraArgs` argument for the `download_file` function, as follows:

```
bucket_name = 'sentinel-s2-l1c'
key = 'tiles/7/W/FR/2018/3/31/0/B01.jp2'
file_name = 'B01.jp2'

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.download_file(bucket_name, key, file_name, ExtraArgs={'RequestPayer': 'requester'})
```

Answer (score 0):

I also found an alternative, run the `s3api` cli as a subprocess. A working shell command:

```
$ aws s3api get-object --bucket sentinel-s2-l1c --key tiles/10/T/DM/2018/8/1/0/B801.jp2 --request-payer requester /home/sam/Desktop/B01.jp2
```

and the python3.6 equivalent:

```
import subprocess

bucket = 'sentinel-s2-l1c'
band = 'B01'

key = f'tiles/10/T/DM/2018/8/1/0/{band}.jp2'
outfile = f'/home/sam/Desktop/{band}.jp2'

subprocess.run(['aws', 's3api', 'get-object', '--bucket', bucket, '--key', key, '--request-payer', 'requester', outfile])
```

This will work as long as `~/.aws/config` is setup, i.e.

```
$ aws configure
```